# Saving Power :: Reducing Power Consumption

Tags: arduino-nano, power, iot, imu

For Arduino Nano 33 IoT, I want to turn off everything except Bluetooth and Wireless since I don't use them.

My question please: Can I switch off / deactivate the IMU sensors completely? If yes, How please?